# How to extract the closest node.js version used from existing package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, package-lock.json, npm-shrinkwrap

My `package-lock.json` and `package.json` do not specify the node.js version used to generate the `package-lock.json` in my repo.

I can iterate over `node` versions using `nvm` to see which one yeilds minimal `git diff` to the previous `package-lock` file in my repo. I wonder it there is a less exhaustive and cumbersum way to do that. Are there any hints to "**reverse engineer**" or "extract" the node-version from the lock file?

Motivation: I don't want to keep changing my `package-lock.json` at each commit, and also use the same node version in the CI consistently.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the "Motivation"? Is `package-lock.json` really changing on each commit? is your node_modules versions are locked (not using ^ or ~)?

Comment: @Daniel I searched this because I have an old electron project that did not use a `.nvmrc` file and I need to know which node ver was used to do `npm i --build-from-source` as i am having issues with apple silicon and some usb dependencies

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: No. I moved away from that and this question never occurred to me again. But it would be nice if some solution exists. The need was only once for me.